# Transfer HTML elements from one list to another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have a problem with the following JavaScript function. I have two UL and I need that when the user clicks on a LI, this element transfers to the other UL.

I've managed to move them `onClick` from on list to the other, the problem appears when I try to move again a LI that was previously in the other UL, when that happens it just doesn't work...

```
    function testList() {
    usersA = document.getElementById("users-a");
    usersB = document.getElementById("users-b");
    
    for (var i=0; i < usersA.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++) {
        usersA.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = function() {
            transfer = this.cloneNode(true);
            usersB.appendChild(transfer);
            usersA.removeChild(this);
            return false;
        }

    }
    for (var i=0; i < usersB.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++) {          
        usersB.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = function() {
            transfer = this.cloneNode(true);
            usersA.appendChild(transfer);
            usersB.removeChild(this);
            return false;
        }

    }
    
}
```

I know that my logic sucks but it's all I could come up with. Any ideas why it works the first time I transfer a LI but when I try to move back to its original UL it doesn't work?

Comment: My eyes, they bleed. I mean calling gEBTN twice for every iteration of the loop. It's like you want to anger the gods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even after you've moved an element from list A to list B, it still keeps its old onclick handler, which still says "remove me from list A and add me to list B". You need to change its onclick handler to say "remove me from list B and add me to list A". Here's one way to fix that:

```
var usersA = document.getElementById("users-a");
var usersB = document.getElementById("users-b");

var onclickA;
var onclickB = function() {
        usersA.appendChild(this);
        this.onclick = onclickA;
        return false;
    };
onclickA = function() {
        usersB.appendChild(this);
        this.onclick = onclickB;
        return false;
    };

for (var i=0; i < usersA.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)
    usersA.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = onclickA;
for (var i=0; i < usersB.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)      
    usersB.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = onclickB;
```

(I also got rid of the `cloneNode` stuff, for exactly the reasons that nnnnnn gives.)

Comment: @Raynos: Eh? Are you saying that I shouldn't have fixed the `cloneNode` stuff?

Comment: Hey folks, thanks a lot for this, as you can see I'm a total newbie, but this is extremely useful to me!

Answer (score 4):

You're not "moving" elements, you're creating a copy and deleting the original. Although this seems like a "move" from the user's point of view the new elements that you create do not have click handlers assigned. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode): "Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values but does not copy event listeners."

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild), `.appendChild()` will remove the child from its current parent so you shouldn't need the two-step clone/remove that you are currently doing. I haven't tested it, but perhaps using just `.appendChild()` it will keep the handlers? If so you need to remove that handler and assign a new one to allow for which list it now belongs to.

Or, rewrite your handlers so that they check which list is the current parent (have a look at [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode)) and move to the *other* list as appropriate.

Bearing in mind that click events "bubble up" starting from the target/source element and up through the parent heirarchy you're probably better off setting your click handlers on the parent `<ul>` elements and then testing which `<li>` was clicked. That way you don't have to worry about setting new click handlers on new child `<li>` elements.

```
function testList() {
   var usersA = document.getElementById("users-a"),
       usersB = document.getElementById("users-b");

   usersA.onclick = function(e) {
      // allow for the IE and non-IE way of handling the event object
      if (!e) e = window.event;
      var el = e.target || e.srcElement;

      if (el.tagName === "li") {
         usersB.appendChild(el);
      }
   }

   usersB.onclick = function(e) {
      // allow for the IE and non-IE way of handling the event object
      if (!e) e = window.event;
      var el = e.target || e.srcElement;

      if (el.tagName === "li") {
         usersA.appendChild(el);
      }
   }
}
```

Also, if you're using `.getElementsByTagName()` call it *once* in the loop initialisation and assign the result to a variable, then use the variable - don't keep calling the function again and again to test the length, or to access individual elements inside your loop:

```
for (var i=0, lis = usersA.getElementsByTagName("li"); i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].onclick = function() {
       // etc
    }
}
```